# How can I stop Windows Indexing from running?

Tags: windows-xp, search

[image]XP Pro, SP3.

I now use "Everything" for search. How can I stop Windows Indexing from running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. In the "Start" menu, choose "Run."
> 2. Type "services.msc" and press Enter.
> 3. Scroll-down to "Indexing Service" and double-click it.
> 4. If the service status is "Running", then stop it by pressing the "Stop" button.
> 5. To make sure this service doesn't run again, under "Startup Type:", choose "Disabled."

— [Lifehacker - Turn off indexing and speed up Windows XP](http://lifehacker.com/031440/turn-off-indexing-and-speed-up-windows-xp)

Comment: Sounds good, but when I go there, it is not running and it is disabled, but it still comes up?????

Comment: *What* comes up?

Comment: I edited my answer to include a graphic. Thanks.

Comment: @Xavierjazz: I'm still wondering *what* comes up. You said "but *it* still comes up". What is *it*?

Comment: THe graphic I added to my question is what appears. That's what I meant.

Comment: @Xavierjazz: Well, that means it is disabled.

Comment: @Xavierjazz: Check for other `Search` related services, there might be multiple (I heard they messed around with that in XP). There's also a Windows Desktop Search entry in `msconfig`, I believe...

Comment: My computer crashed and when I took it in, the tech stopped all unnecessary services.

Comment: @Xavierjazz: That's handy, glad you got it resolved. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hit Windows-R, type "services.msc", and disable "Indexing Service".